# Why does the 'find' command fail without an error?

Tags: linux, find

**NOTE**
It seems I have forget to mention that this only happens after a reboot.  Once booted, it doesn't matter if I run the command 5 mins after boot or 3 days after boot.  But once `find` is run, it will always find it (even after 5 mins or 3 days).

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Linux 4.9.17-v7+.  I don't know why this is happening, but everytime I log into the machine and try to find a known png file, the prompt returns as if there are no result.  Knowing that the file exists, I run the same command again (up arrow key) and it returns with the proper results.

How can I get 2 different results (or inconsistant results) with the find command?  Might there be a package I'm missing?

Proof of the file's existance:

```
me@here:~ $ ls -la /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-default.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1168926 Mar 30 19:51 ls -la /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-default.png
```

But when I run the find command, the prompt returns with no results or errors:

```
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name *default.png
me@here:~ $
```

If I run the find command again, I get these results:

```
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name *default.png
/opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-default.png
me@here:~ $
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I missing a package?  Has a program gone corrupt?  When I'm searching for something and I get no results, how do I know if it exists or not?  Please help me!

**UPDATE 1:**
Comment request.

Running the command with the `-name` argument quoted:

```
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name '*default.png'
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name '*default.png'
/opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-default.png
me@here:~ $
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Taking the sd card to another computer, mounting it and doing the search again `sudo find /mnt/flash -name '*default.png'` produced the correct results.  So it has to be either the OS or possibly a hardware problem.

**UPDATE 3:**
I loaded a fresh OS onto the Raspberry Pi 3 and took the offending 'sd card/OS' and mounted it on the Raspberry Pi 3.  This was to see if it might be a hardware error.   `sudo find /mnt/flash -name '*default.png'` produced the correct results.  So it has to be the OS.

Originally, I took RetroPie v4.2, stopped it from automatically running.  Took my entertainment software and compiled it.  Set it up to run on boot along with lirc.  An option in the entertainment software is to run Emulationstation (the command you comment out to stop the automatic running of the emulation software on boot).  It all works.  So I don't know what would cause this issue.

As far as I know, the /opt directory that the file is contained in is no different from any other.

**UPDATE 4:**
Ok, before searching for '*default.png' I did `sudo find / -name 'hostname'` and it came back with correct results.  Then I ran `sudo find / -name '*default'` and it found it.  So only the first `find` command *might* fail.  Subsequent ones all seem to work.

**UPDATE 5:**
I was able to locate another OS where the first `find` doesn't always work.  I have another Raspberry Pi 1 Model B that is running Arch Linux 4.1.7-2-ARCH.  It doesn't contain the png I've been searching for, but I searched for it anyway.

```
me@there:~ $ sudo find / -name '*default.png'
me@there:~ $ sudo find / -name '*default.png'
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/8x8/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/22x22/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/22x22/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/emblems/emblem-default.png
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/status/avatar-default.png
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gtk3/window-default.png
me@there:~ $
```

So 2 different OS's and 2 different Raspberry Pi's have the same problem.  I've tested this on my Banana Pi and the result are correct the first time.

**UPDATE 6:**
Ok, updates on some comments.
Yes, the file `retropie-default.png` is on the root directory, and there are no autofs/unionfs anywhere on the system.

`sudo find /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/ -name '*default.png'` doesn't behave the same way and does produce the correct results.

Running `sudo date` twice does produce the correct results.

Please read to note at the beginning of this post as I forgot one important point.

I'll be running strace later today.

**UPDATE 7:**
Listing the directory before the `find` command still produces that same results.

```
me@here:~ $ ls /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/
LICENSE                             retropie-2015-carbon-video.mp4
README.md                           retropie-2015.png
retropie-2013.png                   retropie-default-16x10.png
retropie-2014.png                   retropie-default-4x3.png
retropie-2015-4x3.png               retropie-default.png
retropie-2015-carbon-video-4x3.mp4
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name '*2013.png'
me@here:~ $ sudo find / -name '*2013.png'
/opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-2013.png
me@here:~ $
```

**UPDATE 8:**
`sudo strace -o log1 find / -name '*default.png' and then sudo strace -o log2 find / -name '*default.png'`  These log files are huge. What is it that I'm looking for in it? Doing cat logn|grep 'x' where x is 'warning, Warning, WARNING, error, Error, ERROR. What else should I check for? There is a size difference in the log files log1 = 9.9M and log2 = 13 M

I did notice at the end of both log files that there is a different command in log2. `munmap(0x76f31000, 4096)` is not in log1.  Maybe this is where the failure lies?

Comment: This is a typical problem when you [don't quote the argument to -name](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2061). Use `sudo find / -name '*default.png'` instead. However, issuing this exact command twice in the same directory with no other activity in between shouldn't result in different output, so there may be something else going on. Please try to reproduce it with a quoted argument.

Comment: @thatotherguy Quoting the -name argument still produced the same results.

Comment: Please edit the question with the improved commands and output

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the same behavior with any other file?

Comment: If you put that pi's storage  card into a laptop or something and try to do the same find, what's the result of that?

I suspect that can be a) some process dropping / recreating stuff b) an off mechanical connection / reader

Comment: @Ivan Updated with your ideas.  I believe your option A to be most likely.

Comment: Is `/opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/retropie-default.png` on the same fs as `/`? Is there any autofs/unionfs anywhere on the system?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes it is on the root '/' directory.  No autofs/unionfs on the system.

Comment: @Deanie could you please reproduce it once again running with `strace` (to log syscalls - maybe we'll find some leads there)? Is there anything in dmesg between the runs of the find?

Comment: What @Ivan suggest means executing `sudo strace -o log1 find / -name '*default.png'` and then `sudo strace -o log2 find / -name '*default.png'`. Then compare those two files `log1`/`log2`. Be warned that the log files might get quite large.

Comment: I wonder if `sudo find /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/ -name '*default.png'` behaves the same? If it does it might be better to run `strace` with this directory instead....good luck! PS: Just to assure `sudo` works as it should -- does `sudo date` called twice give you correct outputs?

Comment: @Ivan @vlp These log files are huge.  What is it that I'm looking for in it?  Doing `cat logn|grep 'x'` where x is 'warning, Warning, WARNING, error, Error, ERROR.  What else should I check for?  There is a size difference in the log files `log1 = 9.9M` and `log2 = 13 M`

Comment: I guess you can cut the size slightly but triggering the search not from the root directory but something closer to the problematic files, is the issue reproducible in that case?

@vlp is correct in that I would compare the diff, I don't have a concrete idea of what is wrong there

Comment: I would use some tool like [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to visually compare the logs as (unfortunately) there will be many false differences (timestamps,  memory addresses, etc...). Nevertheless as the captured log files are that much different in size, there will definitely be some obvious part which should reveal something...

Answer (score 1):

You can see 'find' manpage to get the answer. If you want to use regex in your command, you must quote the regex.
Your command should be `sudo find / -name \*default.png` or `sudo find / -name '*default.png'`

#### Manpage Reference Below

NON-BUGS

“paths must precede expression” error message

`$ find . -name *.c -print
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D ... [path...] [expression]`

This  happens because `*.c` has been expanded by the shell resulting in find actually receiving a command line like this (If there are `frcode.c locate.c word_io.c` files in `.` folder):

`find . -name frcode.c locate.c word_io.c -print`

That command is of course not going to work.  Instead of doing  things  this  way,  you  should enclose the pattern in quotes or escape the wildcard:

`$ find . -name '*.c' -print
$ find . -name \*.c -print`

Comment: note the same behaviour occurs when quoting the name

Comment: technically it is a glob, not a regular expression (regex)